# Using thread-local resources with parallel for loops

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

Imagine a long list of data to be processed. Processing is CPU bound and can be done in parallel.

To process a data item requires a large object (~50MB) to hold intermediate processing results. This object may be re-used during the processing of a subsequent task.

I want to do something like this:

```
Processor[] processors = GetProcessors(Environment.ProcessorCount);

Parallel.For(
    0,
    itemCount,
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount },
    item =>
    {
        int threadIndex = /* TODO */;
        processors[threadIndex].Process(item);
    }
);
```

The goal is to only ever have `Environment.ProcessorCount` instances of my large object, and reuse them as efficiently as possible.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to [use the overload of `Parallel.For`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783299%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes in the two functions to set up and tear down your thread local object.

```
Parallel.For(
    0,
    itemCount,
    () => new Processor(),
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount },
    (item, loopState, processor) =>
    {
        processor.Process(item);

        // return the processor to be used for another invocation
        return processor;
    }
    processor => 
    {
        //Do any tear down work you need to do, like dispose the object if it is disposeable
        processor.Dispose();
    }
);
```

Because the `Parallel` class function do not immediately jump to using `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` threads (they start at one thread then ramp up to the max you defined) it will only create one instance of `Processor` if only one thread gets created and have up to `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` objects created at the same time.

I do not know the implementation details of the default scheduler but it may or may not stop threads then create new ones causing a new `Processor` object to be created. However, if that happens (which it may not, I don't know) you will still only have a maximum of `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` objects existing at the same time.

Comment: Looks interesting. Unfortunately in my specific case I have an outer loop with this parallel loop inside. I need to re-use the objects across all iterations of the outer loop. I tried using the overload you show to assign integer indices to the threads, but it didn't work. But your answer is probably the perfect scenario for someone who doesn't need to reuse resources in the way that I am. I could merge the two loops into one, but it would make the code unreadable. The outer loop runs on the order of 10 times, where the inner one runs around 1000 times.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that works. I devised this answer while writing the question, but thought the question was interesting enough to post anyway. If someone has a better solution, I'd like to learn it.

Use a concurrent collection (such as `ConcurrentQueue<Processor>`) to allocate instances of the `Processor` between threads.

```
Processor[] processors = GetProcessors(Environment.ProcessorCount);
var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Processor>(processors);

Parallel.For(
    0,
    itemCount,
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount },
    item =>
    {
        // Obtain the processor
        Processor processor;
        queue.TryDequeue(out processor);

        processor.Process(item);

        // Store the processor again for another invocation
        queue.Enqueue(processor);
    }
);
```

An actual implementation should assert that `TryDequeue` returns true, and also enqueue the processors again in case of an exception.

So long as the processing time is much larger than the time spent in queue contention, the overhead should be minimal.

Comment: Yeh interesting. This is essentially a pool of resources implemented as a circular buffer/queue, where we'd initialise the pool with N resources, where N is MaxDegreeOfParallelism and thus TryDequeue should in principle always succeed. I just wonder if there are scenarios where it would fail thus requiring a retry, I can't think of a reason why that would happen though. There is also the synchronisation cost of communicating with the pool, but I think I could live with that rather than recreating the resources for each call to Parallel.For.